# Using Calendar to get exact amount of days Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, time, calendar

I am fairly new to swift and I am trying to use the build-in Calendar in Swift to find the right amount of days and parse it to my date variable, how do I do that? Atm my time Span is just hardcoded but that is not reliable in the long term. I need to go back example 1 month.

```
   switch data {
                case .failure(_):
                    print("No access to quote data")
                    break
                        
                case .success(let data):
                    let startDate = Date()
                        cropClient.delegate = auth
                        var timeSpan: Int
                        var date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: timeSpan, to: startDate)
                        
                        switch configuration.timeSpan {
                            case .unknown:
                                return
                            case .week:
                                timeSpan = -7
                            case .1month:
                                timeSpan = -30
                            case .3months:
                                timeSpan = -90
                            case .year:
                                timeSpan = -365
                        }
    }
```

Comment: Move you `var date = ` line to after switch block. Else looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that your `switch` statement needs to determine two variables - The calendar unit and the quantity, not just the quantity.  This way you will get the correct date regardless of the number of days in a month or the year.

```
let startDate = Date()
        
let timeSpan: Int
let calendarUnit: Calendar.Component
        
switch configuration.timeSpan {
case .unknown:
    return
case .week:
    timeSpan = -7
    calendarUnit = .day
case .oneMonth:
    timeSpan = -1
    calendarUnit = .month
case .threeMonths:
    timeSpan = -3
    calendarUnit = .month
case .year:
    timeSpan = -1
    calendarUnit = .year
}
let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: calendarUnit, value: timeSpan, to: startDate)
```

Comment: I just fixed it using this solution just 2 minutes before you answered, but awesome to know I was on the right path! Thanks anyways :-)